# How to extract first and second columns from a file that contains tabular data

Tags: shell, awk, sed, grep

Consider the following file, holding network client data in a tabular format:

```
                <H2>Welcome to CCcam 2.1.3 server </H2>
            Connected clients: 75
            +------------+---------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------------+----------+
            | Username   | Host          | Connected  | Idle time  | ECM       | EMM | Version| Last used share                              | Ecm time |
            +------------+---------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------------+----------+
    |user4       |1x3.xxx.126.xx |00d 22:53:52|00d 22:53:52|0 (0)      |0 (0)|2.1.3   |                                              |          |
    |useral      |7x.xx.xxx.1xx  |00d 22:53:52|00d 22:53:52|0 (0)      |0 (0)|2.0.11  |                                              |          |
    |userxxxx    |x7.xx5.xx.1x1  |00d 22:53:52|00d 22:53:52|0 (0)      |0 (0)|2.0.11  |                                              |          |
    |someuse     |9x.8x.xx0.xx4  |00d 22:53:52|00d 00:00:15|8248 (8245)|0 (0)|2.1.4   |UPC 1W - Zone Reality Europe [CW2] (ok)       |  0.3060s |
    |nameuse     |x8.xx3.6x.7x   |00d 22:53:51|00d 22:53:51|0 (0)      |0 (0)|2.2.1   |                                              |          |
    |blabl       |xx.2xx.x.x4    |00d 22:53:50|00d 00:00:00|4282 (2541)|0 (0)|2.1.4   |Total TV - Fox TV Serbia [NDS] (ok)           |  0.1099s |
    |aaaaaa      |xx9.x3.4x.2x   |00d 22:53:49|00d 00:56:41|1753 (1536)|0 (0)|2.1.4   |Total TV - OBN [NDS] (nok)                    |  0.1264s | 

+------------+---------------+------------+------------+-----------+-----+--------+----------------------------------------------+----------+

    +------------+---------------------------------------+
    | Username   | Shareinfo                             |
    +------------+---------------------------------------+
    |       user3|                                       |
    |      user33|                                       |
    |    user2222|                                       |
    |     user333|local 0d02:000000 6589(6588)           |
    |            |remote 0d02:000000 756(755)            |
    |            |remote 1802:000000 853(852)            |
    |            |local 1802:000000 50(50)               |
    |     user444|                                       |
    |       user3|local 091f:000000 2154(2147)           |
    |            |remote 091f:000000 394(394)            |
    |            |local 1802:000000 1734(0)              |
    |      USER22|local 091f:000000 1677(1509)           |
    |            |local 0d02:000000 4(3)                 |
    |            |local 1802:000000 70(22)               |
    |            |remote 091f:000000 1(1)                |
    |            |remote 1802:000000 1(1)                |
    |       USER1|local 0d02:000000 3359(3357)           |
    |            |remote 0d02:000000 165(165)            | 
    +------------+---------------------------------------+
```

How con we extract the two first columns of this file, that is, fields `user` and `ip address`, so that output would look like this:

```
user4  1x3.xxx.126.xx
useral 7x.xx.xxx.1xx 
userxxxx x7.xx5.xx.1x1 
someuse 9x.8x.xx0.xx4  
nameuse x8.xx3.6x.7x
blabl xx.2xx.x.x4    
aaaaaa xx9.x3.4x.2x
```

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN { FS = "|" }

/Last used share/ { next }

{ if(NF == 11) print $2, $3 }
```

---

Update: The operating instructions...

```
$ awk -f test.awk < cam.txt
user4        1x3.xxx.126.xx 
useral       7x.xx.xxx.1xx  
userxxxx     x7.xx5.xx.1x1  
someuse      9x.8x.xx0.xx4  
nameuse      x8.xx3.6x.7x   
blabl        xx.2xx.x.x4    
aaaaaa       xx9.x3.4x.2x
```

Or, `someprogram | awk -f test.awk`

Comment: Thx for quick answer but where to put input file?

Comment: ..and how to include here:someprogram | awk -f test.awk this script?

Comment: ok understand the right way is:
awk -f filename_of_script /partof_inputfile > outputfile
THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Comment: `someprogram | awk -F '|' '!/Last used share/ && NF == 11'` is all it takes.

Comment: `awk -F'|' '!/Username/ && NF==11{print $2,$3} /path/to/file` is a bit simpler

Comment: @SiegeX: Except that yours is correct, because in my cleverness of using an implicit `print` I overlooked the fact that the OP only wanted two fields and not the whole line. By the way, where I come from it's "jinx - you own me a Coke!"

Comment: Heh, all that code-golf, and then I go leave out some good compression. Nice job.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand to apply the techniques developed in the answer to the question "[How to parse rackspace big data api response using shell scripting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25600134/2654678)”. In your special case, this yields:

```
# ccam_canonize
#  Canonize output of ccam report tools
ccam_canonize()
{
  sed -e '1,3d;/^+[-+]*$/d;s/^| //;s/ |$//;s/ | /|/g;/Shareinfo/,$d'
}

# ccam_extract
#  Extract user and IP
ccam_extract()
{
  awk -F'|' '{print($1,$2)}'
}

ccam_canonize | ccam_extract
```